# Automatic calculation in one attribute table based on values in another attribute table using python

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, arcpy, fields-attributes

I am trying to fill the fields of one gdb table based on some statistics over the attributes of another shape file. As it was not possible in ARCgis directly, I am trying to use python coe for this case.

I have table A where:

Work_done   Length
  1
  50
  100

I would like to say that fill the legth field with sum of the Shape_Length in table B where "work_Done" field is equal another feild in table B.

the following code is what I am thinking and I want to use it in the field_calculator but I got failed. I am not really pro in python therfore I would be really happy if sombody could guide me.

```
  import arcpy

  from arcpy import env

  # Set the current workspace 
  env.workspace = "C:/Python27/ArcGIS10.1"


  table = "Corriodr_stat.dbf"
  ft = "Length"
  fc = "Corridor_test.shp"
  f1, f2 = "Corridor_S", "SHAPE_Leng"


  for row1 in sorted(arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, [f1, f2])):
     for row2 in sorted(arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, [ft])):
        if fc.f1 <= 1:
           table.row2 = getvalueField(sum row1.f2)
        elif (fc.f1 > 1 and fc.f1 <= 60)
           table.row2 = getvalueField(sum row1.f2)
        elif (fc.f1 > 60 and fc.f1 <= 100):
           table.row2 = getvalueField(sum row1.f2)
```

Comment: There are a lot of errors in your code: 1.  The indentation is wrong.  2. What is `valueTable`?  You assign a value to it, but the variable is never used.  3. `fc` is a string, and has no attribute `Corridor_S`. Maybe it would be easier to help if you post the exact error message you're getting.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Well the indentation is correct in my original code just when I copied it here , I did not orginized it nicely. by 'valuetable' I mean the assigned valuein the row. The 'fc' is my Feature class and has different Attribute as' Corridor_S'. I got the error' Paratmeters are not valid'

Comment: Please correct the indentation in your question then.  I have a few comments, which I'll post as an answer

Comment: i have changed the code partly. I would be happy to have your helpful comments :)

Answer (score 3):

The basic problem is the assumption that referring to a feature classes or table by name gives it any intelligence, and to be able to write any substantial python code you need to understand basic python types, and I suggest you find a basic python tutorial (not an ArGIS/python tutorial!)

1. `fc` is not a feature class, it is a string which happens to contain the path to a feature class.  As far as python is concerned its just a bunch of characters, and would be treated exactly the same if you wrote `fc = 'I am not a feature class'`.  The line `rowsFc = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc)` calls a function (`SearchCursor`) which takes the path to a feature class, opens the feature class and returns a search cursor to it.
2. See 1.  `fc` is a string, and strings do not have an attribute `Corridor_S`.  A record returned by a cursor in the feature class may though, so this might run:

   ```
   for row in rowsFc:
       print(row.Corridor_S)
   ```
3. `valueTable` is not a table, it is just a variable, so storing a value to it doesn't mean that anything is going to be written to a database table.  It is possible that you want something along the lines of:

   ```
   for row in rowsTable:
       row.valueField = 42
   ```

Without the full error including traceback, it is not really possible to say what the error you're experiencing is, but your code certainly won't run unless you fix these errors.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and good comments. Well, I am not pro in coding specially python and I am just trying to get an an idea based on the avavilabe codes. Foe instance in the following link they have caled Feature class as I did. what is your idea about it?http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000011000000

Comment: Nothing wrong with the syntax there, but I suggest you make sure you understand it before trying to use it.

Comment: I have edited the code based on your guidance. I would be thnakful if you kindly check it and give me your Feedback. thanks